# How to perform 'group by' then append each group with same rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, append

First i need to filter/ group row with unique values from 'set' column then create same 2 new rows for each filter/ group

Also it is very important to get the name of each gruop and pass it to column  'set' value

`'set' : name,`

data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 1, 'yes'], [1, 1, 0, 'no'],[1, 3, 0, 'no'],[2, 1, 0,'no'],[2, 2, 0,'yes'], [2, 3, 1,'no'], [3, 3, 1,'no'],[3, 1, 1,'no'],[3, 2, 1, 'no']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'set'])
df
```

[image]

```
groups = df.groupby("set") 
for name, group in groups: 
        
    group = group.append({'a' : 12 , 'b' : 7, 'set' : name, }, ignore_index=True)
    group = group.append({'a' : 12 , 'b' : 8, 'set' : name, },  ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. `x.name` will give you group name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `apply`:

```
def addRows(x):
     # <new_rows> write your values 
     x = x.append(new_rows)

df.groupby('set').apply(addRows).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Edit:**

```
def addRows(x):
    set_name = (x.name) # <--- this will give you name.
    x = x.append({'a' : 12 , 'b' : 7, 'set' : set_name, }, ignore_index=True)
    x = x.append({'a' : 12 , 'b' : 8, 'set' : set_name, },  ignore_index=True)
    return x # <--- need to return


df.groupby('set').apply(addRows).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    a   b   c   set
0   1   1   0   no
1   1   3   0   no
2   2   1   0   no
3   2   3   1   no
4   3   3   1   no
5   3   1   1   no
6   3   2   1   no
7   12  7   NaN no
8   12  8   NaN no
9   1   2   1   yes
10  2   2   0   yes
11  12  7   NaN yes
12  12  8   NaN yes
```

Comment: @mikel324: Now check I have updated my answer

Comment: in my code name = name of the group (i.e. yes or no ), it was not just a string

Comment: @mikel324 you can get the group name by using `x.iloc[x.index]['set']` something like this :)